# Update Debian8 JRE 1.7 => 1.8

Tags: linux, debian, java, jre, openjdk

The OpenJDK website reports installation is a simple one line operation.  Debian/Ubunutu is specifically referenced in the instructions.
http://openjdk.java.net/install/

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

However, on Debian8 x64, I receive this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-9-jre
```

Debian Package Search reports this is not available:
https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=openjdk-8-jre

That link only offers headless, Zero/Shark, JamVM versions which I don't think I need for basic java development.

Also searched for solutions including:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/504276/how-do-i-use-apt-to-install-32-bit-openjdk-7-jre-on-azure-amd64-ubuntu-server-14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it turns out that openjdk-8-jre is in the testing debian release and not yet stable.  Good job openJDK website :)

add a deb line to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian testing main
```

now apt-get install works

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

Comment: java -version still reports 1.7.0_79 :(

Comment: You probably need to use `update-alternatives` to change to change the default version.

Comment: BE CAREFUL! When adding testing repos many of the core libraries on your system will be updated which is probably not what you want.